# Relay/GraphQL Schema cache not updating when I update schema on server side

Tags: node.js, caching, reactjs, relayjs, graphql-js

I have a React app using Relay and a remote GraphQL server.  When I start the webpack server, I have it fetch the latest schema and feed it into the babel-relay-plugin.

It works great....except when I make a schema change.  It appears React or Relay or webpack or something is caching the schema, because I'll get a Schema validation error in the browser console when I run the app.  However, when I run the query manually against the GraphQL server using GraphIQL, the query is successful.  So it would have to be some sort of cache on the react, relay, webpack side I'm thinking?

Things I've tried:

1. List item
2. Restarting webpack server
3. Removing `node_modules` and `npm install`
4. I've even tried restarting my computer (that actually seemed to work, but may be coincidence)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I have observed the same issue and have yet to find a solution for it.

Comment: have you tried changing something in a js file to force a recompile, maybe it does not detect a change in js so it does not recompile. This has worked on occasions. I suspect that webpack might also be caching things and together with `HotModuleReplacment` there might be more issues. Not sure though.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. :-/  Doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Yes, it hasnt worked reliably for me as well.

Comment: Did you ever find a reliable solution @postalservice14?

Comment: @ChrisEdwards yeah I did, thanks for reminding me to update this.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, of course, it was human error.  I had cacheDirectory as `true` in my babel-loader query.  You can read about it on the babel-loader readme (just do a find on page for 'cacheDirectory') https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

Once I changed that to `false`, which is the default.  The problem went away. Hope that helps others.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I switched to Webpack 2.

The solution in my case was to move the `babelRelayPlugin` to be the first plugin to execute in `.babelrc`.

I'm not exactly sure on the why though.

Comment: I have it at first position. However I am still observing the same problem.